# React Formik props isSubmitted with react-query do not take affect

Tags: formik, react-query

I have my Formik form below (I'm new with formik). An this is the simple form which have two fields  and makes api call using react-query (react -query works well).

But the problem is that formik state `isSubmitting` do not take effect when click. (Button do not start spinning, but if it is direct true, it works well)

I wonder what i'm missing? Why it has no effect? and How it could be solved?

Api Call:

```
const createUser = async ({name, password}: Record<string, string>) => {
    return await axiosInstance.post(`users/create_user/`, {
        name: name,
        password: password,
    });
};
```

React-query Mutation:

```
const createNewUser = useMutation(createUser, {
        onSuccess: () => {
            queryClient.refetchQueries(["getAllUsers"])
        },

        onError: (newUser) => {
            console.log("onError", newUser);
        }
```

Formik Form:

```
<Formik
                initialValues={{ username: username, password: password }}
                validateOnChange={false}
                validateOnBlur={false}

                onSubmit={(values, {setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
                    setSubmitting(true)
                    
                    createNewUser.mutate({

                        name: values.username,

                        password: values.password,
                    });

                    setSubmitting(false);
                    resetForm();

                }}
            >
                {({ values, errors, isSubmitting, handleSubmit }) => (
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <div>
                            <label
                                htmlFor="Имя"
                                className="block text-900 font-medium mb-2"
                            >

                            </label>
                            <Field
                                type="text"
                                name="username"
                                className="w-full mb-3"
                                as={InputText}
                            />
                            <Field
                                type="text"
                                name="password"
                                className="w-full mb-3"
                                as={InputText}
                            />

                        <Button
                            label="save new user"
                            icon="pi pi-user"
                            className="w-full"
                            type="submit"
                            loading={isSubmitting} // to not take effect? why?
                        />

                        </div>

                    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `setTimeout`,  to `setSubmitting(false)` after few seconds not immediately like this:

```
setTimeout(() => setSubmitting(false), 2000);
```

Or, check if mutation is successfully executed, then `setSubmitting` to false

```
if(createNewUser.status == 'success' || createNewUser.status == 'error') {
   setSubmitting(false);
}
```

Alternatively, without using formik `isSubmitting` you can use
`createNewUser.isLoading`

```
<Button
  label="save new user"
  icon="pi pi-user"
  className="w-full"
  type="submit"
  loading={createNewUser.isLoading} 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this one is good: {createNewUser.isLoading}